# How does this code work? Changing labels?

Tags: python, tkinter

I found this piece of code online. I have a few questions about it. When I run the program, it says "is equivalent to" # meters. Where/how is the # being switched out? Is it being switched out by using a label? How is it that the labels aren't overlapping every time you hit calculate? Thanks.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def calculate(*args):
    try:
        value = float(feet.get())
        meters.set((0.3048 * value * 10000.0 + 0.5)/10000.0)
    except ValueError:
        pass

root = Tk()
root.title("Feet to Meters")

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

feet = StringVar()
meters = StringVar()

feet_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=7, textvariable=feet)
feet_entry.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(W, E))

ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=meters).grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(W, E))
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Calculate", command=calculate).grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=W)

ttk.Label(mainframe, text="feet").grid(column=3, row=1, sticky=W)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="is equivalent to").grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=E)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="meters").grid(column=3, row=2, sticky=W)

for child in mainframe.winfo_children():
    child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)

feet_entry.focus()
root.bind('<Return>', calculate)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following in your interactive Python shell to understand what’s going on:

```
>>> from tkinter import *
>>> root = Tk()
>>> myvar = StringVar()
>>> Label(root, text='Before').pack(side=LEFT)
>>> Label(root, textvar=myvar).pack(side=LEFT)
>>> Label(root, text='After').pack(side=LEFT)
```

Now change the value of `myvar` using the `set` method and watch what happens to the window:

```
>>> myvar.set('foo bar')
```

Answer (score 0):

`meters` is defined as a `StringVar`, and one of the labels is defined using `textvariable=meters`. The label therefore takes its value directly from the `StringVar`, so when you change the variable with `meters.set`, the label's value changes automatically. Handy feature to know about!